# Run php command with Boost::Process

Tags: php, boost, process, stdout, permission-denied

I try to run PHP script and to get the ouput from stdout, the code looks like this:

```
using namespace boost::process;

std::string exec="php";
std::vector<std::string> args;

// I must to throw the exe by argument
args.push_back("php");
args.push_back("a.php");

context ctx;
ctx.stdout_behavior = capture_stream();
child c = launch(exec, args, ctx);

pistream &is = c.get_stdout();
```

There is no info at stdout, but at stderr I get:

"boost::process::detail::posix_start: execve(2) failed: Permission denied"

And when I run exactly same command in terminal it works fine!

Any solutions?

Thanks..

Comment: Get permissions inside boost, too (not only in terminal), and you should be fine.

Comment: How to "get permissions inside boost"?
I tried to run my app from the terminal with sudo, but it didn't help...

Comment: It's likely that it runs under a different user. Either change the user or make that user allow to execute the script, too. Are you working on a unixoide system?

Comment: I have no (zero) experience with boost, however this sounds like a conflict with ACLs in your file-system. Check the permissions of the file you would like to exec (php).

Comment: Thanks, you gave me right direction!
I went to /usr/bin/ to check the permission and saw php5 command with same permisions (php is link to php5).
I don't understand why, but when I replaced the command to php5, the previous error replaced by "No such file or directory",
and when I gave full path, it works fine:

    exec="/usr/bin/php5";
    args.clear();
    args.push_back("php5");

Comment: Ah! Well, the `$PATH` variable was different. Didn't thought about that.

Comment: And: Put your solution as an answer below with some description. You can accept it later. It's totally okay to answer your own questions.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: Ah I see. Now you have 11 reputation. ;) Let me know if you still run into a problem via comments here.

Comment: Hhh... Thanks!
It's my first question =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @hakre, you gave me right direction!

I went to /usr/bin/ to check the permission and saw php5 command with same permissions as php (php is link to php5).

I don't understand why, but when I replaced the command to php5, the previous error replaced by: "No such file or directory", and when I gave full path, it works fine:

```
exec="/usr/bin/php5";
args.clear();
args.push_back("php5");
```